# How to add cyclomatic complexity to sonar-cxx?

Tags: c++, sonarqube, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm trying to add lizard report (https://github.com/terryyin/lizard) to sonar in order to create issues over functions are over a threshold

There are any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonar have his own cyclomatic-complexity calculation, so I dont need to import external report (lizard).

To create issue is as easy as activate new rules on Quality Profiles with tag brain-overload:

- Files should not be too complex : default threshold 200
- Functions should not be too complex : default 10, in my case I let 30